# How to create objects in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I've been coding a game in Javascript, my first, and I'm trying to create objects in an array. I've written the following code but I'm not sure if it works properly. Can somebody verify or correct this?

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    objs [i] = '"i" = {x=(i*100),y=(i*100)}'
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the issue?

Comment: He's trying to put objects inside an array, it isn't working because his syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to put objects in an array.

first declare an array

```
var objs = [];
```

Then do something like

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
    objs[i] = {x:i*100,y:i*100}
}
```

You had a lot of superflous code in there.

You need to learn how to figure out if your code works.  The interpreter chokes on your example as written.  You can open up your web tools, paste your code in, and run it, then start figuring out the errors.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hNLW/) that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var objs = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    objs[i] = {
                  x: (i*100),
                  y: (i*100)
              }
}
```

**Explanation**

First of all you need to declare your array variable `objs`, so write down `var objs = [];`

Then you execute the for loop and assign the value to your array:

```
objs[i] = {
              x: (i*100),
              y: (i*100)
          }
```

You can use either `.push()` function to your array, so the code will be:

```
objs.push({
              x: (i*100),
              y: (i*100)
          });
```

The Javascript syntax for object is `propertyName: propertyValue`. Read more from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)